# How many D batteries would be required to power an 150watt/120volt Light for 8 Hours?

Tags: voltage, power, led, batteries, watts

Here are the links to further data.

- [Bulb info](https://www.1000bulbs.com/product/5721/FL-107176.html?gclid=CjwKCAiA8bnUBRA-EiwAc0hZk_NXGzXmiSCRC9T1obxWfw5vs2PpsjUNT1AT6PDQnZors4yCbyJcnBoCNlcQAvD_BwE).
- [D battery datasheet](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/hr20-2500_eu.pdf).

Comment: What about the data sheet for the D type battery? It cannot be answered without this information. Please provide it.

Comment: http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/hr20-2500_eu.pdf

Comment: add extra information into the OP, not in comments

Comment: Rather than provide you with a direct answer we can help you work it out. (1) From the formula for power given current and voltage \$ P = VI \$ can you work out what current you will need for that lamp? (2) How many batteries will you need to make 120 V?

Comment: This isn't a practical proposition, hence must be homework.

Answer (score 1):

Voltages add.  A D cell is nominally 1.5V, so you would need 80 D Cells in series to reach 120V.

Power is current times voltage.  You have 150W at 120V, so that draws about 1.25A.

Capacity is measured in watt hours (Wh) or ampere hours (Ah.)
 8 hours at 1.25A is 10Ah.

[An alkaline D Cell has a capacity of around 12Ah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_battery)  so if you are lucky you only need  one stack of 80 cells.

Probably better to put a second stack of 80 in parallel.

I checked Amazon.  One stack of 80 will run you to about $60.

You would be better off purchasing a solar panel with a charger and battery.  After just a couple of days that will be cheaper than the D Cells.  $60 a day gets expensive real fast.

---

I posted this with the intent to convince you how impractical your plan is.

Consider how you would connect 80 D cells together.

Consider how much volume you would need to contain that many batteries. (In a school locker? Really?  With an orange tree in there too?)

Consider how often you will have to replace the batteries.  Alkalines are expensive.

If you use rechargeable cells, how do you plan to recharge and replace 80 cells each day?

Answer (score 0):

150W/120V for 8 hours is 1.25A = 10,000mAh

Energizer brand rates its alkaline D cell at approximately 20,000mAh at 25mA draw, but estimates performance closer to about 10,000mAh at 500mA draw

Since you need 120V, that's three parallel strips of about 87 in series, factoring in 0.1R terminal resistance.

So somethere in the neighborhood of 261...

Answer (score 0):

A LOT. It will take 80 D cells just to get to 120V, and then you need to provide at least 10 AH of capacity. You would be better off using an automotive battery and a small inverter.

FWIW - incandescent bulbs are incredibly inefficient at making light. That 150W bulb could be replaced with less than 20 watts of LED lights.

Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Its a grow light.  Don't ask too many questions:  he may be using it to grow weed in his closet.  :)

Comment: Well, its not illegal to grow Basil in your closet. But there are much better ways of doing it, if that's the goal.

Comment: Red+Blue LEDs make much better plant lights than incandescent bulbs, I wonder why those are even manufactured any more.

Comment: We're gonna grow an orange/lemon tree in a school locker

Comment: Well, I would suggest looking into using LED bulbs rather than the one you linked, which is VERY inefficient. LED bulbs use about one tenth of the energy of an incandescent bulb to produce a similar amount of light. Plants will grow well under white LED's there is no need for a "grow" bulb with blue spectrum. After all, the sun is not blue is it?

Comment: Janka - Red and blue...not really. Plants actually grow best under a white light source. White LEDs are what I would recommend.

Comment: An automotive battery will only handle about 12 deep discharge cycles.  Not a good option.   A deep discharge battery like those used for a golf cart would be a good alternative.

Comment: Misunderstood - Yes, you are absolutely right. A marine deep discharge battery would be better.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The battery you linked is 1.2 volts and has a capacity of 2500 mAh falling to a terminal voltage of 1.0 volts. This assumes a current draw of 500 mA and that isn't far off what the lamp takes on full power (1.25 amps).

So, if you accepted a lamp current of only 1 amp you might be able to parallel operate two batteries to give you the 1 amp current, but, you'll need a stack of 100 in series to give you the 120 volts.

With a paralleled capacity of 5000 mAh you'll get five hours service.

If you want more service then parallel three batteries and stack a hundred of them to give to approximately 7.5 hours service and, at a stretch you might get 8 hours if you accepted that the lamp would be a tad dim after the 8 hours running time.

300 batteries is my estimate.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see .

- Required LOAD:  150W*8h @120V  or 1200Wh at 1.25A rate
- Proposed SOURCE: NiMH 1.2~1.0V 2500mAh@500mA
- discharge time for  1 cell = 4.5h = 2500mAh/( 1.1V*500mA) thus 2 shunt battery strings needed at 120V since battery drops from 1.2 to 1.0V
- you need to decide on voltage tolerance and mean voltage thus 100S to 110S(eries)     cells and 2P.
- Recommend: 2P105S = 210 cells

**Check:**  using cell VI curves we get a slightly different answer.

- sharing current in 2 strings 1.25A/2= 625 mA for 500mA we get **3125mWh** for 1.25A we get the same.
  thus for 625mA * 1.25V * 8h = 6.25Wh required per cell and 150W*8h=1200Wh energy load **we need 1200/6.25= 192 cells** which is close or recommendation but we just dont let the lamp drain to zero charge, instead leave 10% SoC balance..

Not a particularily cost effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is not as insane as these guys make it out to be.
Typically this would be powered by a lead acid battery with an inverter.
A NiMH battery is much more reliable and can be cycled more times and handles a deep discharge much better than lead acid.  A lead acid battery that can handle daily deep discharge (e.g. AGM) runs about $200+.

Advantages of NiMH

- Rugged, high cycle count with proper maintenance
- Only battery that can be ultra-fast charged with little stress
- Good load performance; forgiving if abused
- Long shelf life; can be stored in a discharged state, needs priming before use
- Simple storage and transportation; not subject to regulatory control
- Good low-temperature performance
- Economically priced; NiCd is the lowest in terms of cost per cycle
- Available in a wide range of sizes and performance options

You need a 12V inverter with a 120V output. You would connect in parallel multiple sets of 10 (or 11) of the D batteries wired in series.

Your choice of grow bulb is very poor.

You should consider using strips of Samsung Gen3 F-Series  or Bridgelux EB Series Gen2.  These are (today) the most efficient light source for plants.

Here you can use a $5, 175 lm/W Bridgelux BXEB-L0280Z-30E100-C-B3 Strip with a 97% efficient Mean Well LDD-H (step down) or LDB-L (Boost) DC-DC LED driver.  Here you have the flexibility to use input voltages from 2v to 24v and adjust the current (700-1000mA) to the desired brightness.

You could use 22v battery packs designed to be used with power tools with a simple step down buck CC driver.

[**DATASHEET:** Bridgelux EB Series Gen 2](https://www.bridgelux.com/sites/default/files/resource_media/DS131%20Bridgelux%20EB%20Series%20Gen2%20Data%20Sheet%2020171020%20Rev%20A.pdf)

[**DATASHEET:** Mean Well LDB-L](http://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=LDB-L)

[**DATASHEET:** Mean Well LDD-L](http://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=LDD-L)